# Left image to right image warping(2d-2d) using extrinsic parameter after stereo calibration

Tags: geometry, camera-calibration

I want to warp left image to right image. So, goal is warped left image and unwarped right image are same when two image are overlapped.

I have calibration parameter, intrinsic and extrinsic.

In extrinsic parameter, rotation matrix and translation vector are about left camera to right camera. 
ex) translation vector = [128.xx, 0.xx, 1.xx] -> x coordinate between left camera and right camera is 128.xx

And I know fundamental matrix and essential metrics.

As a result, only using this parameter obtained by stereo calibration, how do i warp left image to right image like "rectification" that got hit on the x-axis?

Comment: They cannot be made the same by simply warping. You can pick a plane in the scene and calculate a homography that makes the images of this plane equal but nothing more. Everything else requires per-pixel depth information. Otherwise, what would be the point of having stereo vision if the two images are equal up to some rectification?